# Calculation, replace dot with a comma

Tags: jquery, euro

I have an order form on which I use the jQuery Calculation Plugin to sum up the total.

This summing up works fine, yet there is a problem with the produced 'sum'. In the sum I wish to replace any dot with a comma.

The basis of the code is;

```
function ($this) {
    var sum = $this.sum();
    $("#totaal").html("&euro; " + sum2);
}
```

Using a .replace() directly on the var sum doesn't work (referenced function not available on object). I have also tried this (but without effect);

```
var sum2 = sum.toString().replace(',', '.');
```

As I'm kind of new to jQuery I'm pretty much stuck now, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your replace line is almost right. You need to use a regexp with the `g` option, which says to replace all instances instead of just the first. You also have the order swapped (first is what to find, second is what to replace it with).

```
var sum2 = sum.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
```

Note the `\` before the `.`: `.` has a special meaning in a RegExp, so it has to be escaped.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply's. The above line works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If Sum was a number then this would work.

```
var sum_formatted = String( sum ).replace(/\./g,',');
```

Can you run typeof(sum) and tell us what the output is.

Also if you can set the project up in jsfiddle.com that would be great.

Comment: typeof(sum) returns "Number". Yet the line above doesn't seem to work (it doesn't replace the dot).

Comment: Doesn't work because the order of arguments is still incorrect.

Comment: I actually assumed that YDL wanted to change comma's to dots. Anyway i've changed it around

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your replace function should read `replace('.', ',')` not the other way around (you had `replace(',', '.')`), Note that the first argument is what you're looking for, and the second argument is what you want there instead.  You were replacing all commas with periods.  Regex here is unnecessary.